# python image not found after paraview brew install

Tags: python, numpy, paraview

I am runing python scripts on mac and after a "brew install paraview" a lot of packages are not working anymore : import vtk, or import scipy.linalg ...
Here is for example one of the bug:

Would you have an idea how to fix this?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "MV15.py", line 3, in <module>
    import scipy.linalg as slin   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
    from .misc import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import blas   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/blas.py", line 145, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/libgfortran.3.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.so   Reason: image not found
```